# Error during registration for multiple participants

Tags: civievent

I'm running into an issue for event registrations where multiple participants can be registered.  The first registrant goes through fine, however, when submitting registration #2, the following error occurs:

Call to protected method CRM_Event_Form_Registration_Register::getRegistrationContactID() from context 'CRM_Event_Form_Registration_AdditionalParticipant'

I am running Joomla 3.7.2 and Civicrm 4.7.19

Thoughts on where to go?

Comment: I am using Drupal 7.54 and CiviCRM 4.7.19 and am getting an error when the second participant is entered and then completed. The backtrace can be seen in this link:
[link](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1zyUcOs30vtZuvQaKUuAh8FjiGbovpQW0B2SyWjwRPfE/edit?usp=sharing)
Is anyone else seeing this issue?

Comment: Has anyone reported this issue on issues.civicrm.org? Instead of hacking Civi core, it's better fix this properly.

Comment: I'm getting the same error on Drupal 7.x and Civi 4.7.19

Answer (score 1):

The error is due to call to the protected function `getRegistrationContactID()` in `CRM_Event_Form_Registration_AdditionalParticipant` class for multiple event participants registration.

The issue got resolved in my installation (civicrm 4.7.19) after changing the access control of the function `getRegistrationContactID()` from `protected` to `public`.

The file location is `civicrm-module/CRM/Event/Form/Registration.php`

Comment: I hate to sound like an a** but how would I make that change?

Comment: The file location in the above is incorrect for a Drupal site and should be civicrm/CRM/Event/Form/Registration/Register.php. If I make the change from protected to public in that file it seems to have successfully resolved the issue.

Comment: I am having the same issue on WP 4.7.5 and CiviCRM 4.7.19

PHP error is Call to protected method CRM_Event_Form_Registration_Register::getRegistrationContactID() from context 'CRM_Event_Form_Registration_AdditionalParticipant' in /usr/home/mysite/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Event/Form/Registration/AdditionalParticipant.php on line 613